# Search doesn't work for remote kernel debugging in WinDBG

Tags: debugging, windbg, remote-debugging

I'm trying to do some remote hypervisor kernel debugging in WinDBG (latest version: 10.0.15063.468). The connection is established through the local network, everything works fine, I can break and display the stack or memory, but for some odd reason the search command doesn't work with the simplest stuff:

```
kd> db 0xfffff80002458350 L20
fffff800`02458350  00 00 00 00 40 00 00 42-2e 72 65 6c 6f 63 00 00  ....@..B.reloc..
fffff800`02458360  0c 06 00 00 00 00 40 01-00 08 00 00 00 a0 10 00  ......@.........
kd> s -sa 0xfffff80002458350 L20
fffff800`02458357  "B.reloc"
kd> s -b 0xfffff80002458350 L20 0x6c
kd> s -b 0xfffff80002458350 L20 0x72
kd> s -b 0xfffff80002458350 L100 0x72
kd> s -a 0xfffff80002458350 L100 "reloc"
kd> db 0xfffff80002458350 L20
fffff800`02458350  00 00 00 00 40 00 00 42-2e 72 65 6c 6f 63 00 00  ....@..B.reloc..
fffff800`02458360  0c 06 00 00 00 00 40 01-00 08 00 00 00 a0 10 00  ......@.........
kd> s -b 0xfffff80002458350 L100 'r'
kd> s -b 0xfffff80002458350 L100 'B'
```

Why would "-sa" work and "-b" not - what is this magic? Can anyone explain, or at least point me at how I could find the reason for this bizarre behavior?

Comment: Does it work with older versions of WinDbg?

Comment: No, the same problem occurs in WinDbg 10.0.10075.9 (from 2015).

Comment: iirc search # pattern search all are borked for some time i think i havent used them lately shoot a mail to windbgfb@microsoft.com  with a reprio version os bit etc  andy luhrs will probably respond

Comment: Thanks blabb, I'll give it a shot and report the outcome later.

Comment: In an unexpected turn of events, windbgfb@microsoft.com didn't bother to respond. If anyone has any other tips on how to make this simple WinDbg feature work, I'd be much obliged.